# Where are the preferred argument conversions for overloaded methods documented (if at all)?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, arguments, overloading

In other words, what are the precise rules for how the Java compiler determines which overloaded method to choose to execute?  I've spent a good amount of time googling and I think I'm not using the right search keywords.

```
public class C1  extends C2 {}
public class C2  extends C3 {}
public class C3 {}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        // What are the precise rules for determining 
        // which method below is called?
        method(c1, c1); 
    }

    static public void method(C3 test, C3 test2) {
        System.out.println("C3");
    }

    static public void method(C2 test, C3 test2) {
        System.out.println("C2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of the JLS is [15.12.2 Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#292575).  The rules are complicated and technical, but the general principle is that the applicable method with the most specific argument types is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is stated in the [Java Language Spec, Conversions.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.5)

I can see from there that is must be a widening reference conversion, but I don't see any remarks about the path. It seems to me it searches for the shortest matching path (in the inheritance tree), as that is most logical, but again, I can't find that in the spec.